# Help with the Divergence Test

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have the series
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\ln^{10}k}
\end{equation}
and I want to use the Divergence Test to determine whether it diverges or not. Do I really need to use L'Hôpital's rule 10 times to prove that it diverges?

Comment: You could replace $\sqrt k$ with $k^{1/20}$, and simply show that $\displaystyle\frac {k^{1/20}}{\ln k}\to\infty$. It follows that its $10$-th power, $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt k}{\ln^{10}k}$, also diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for a series to converge, the $n^{th}$ term has to go to zero. However, if we consider the $n^{th}$ term of the series, we have $a_n = \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln^{10}(n)}$. And,
$$\underbrace{\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln^{10}(n)} = \lim_{t\to \infty} \dfrac{e^{t/2}}{t^{10}}}_{n=e^t}$$
Now note that
$$e^{t/2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(t/2)^{k}}{k!} > \dfrac{(t/2)^{11}}{11!}$$
Hence,
$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \dfrac{e^{t/2}}{t^{10}} > \lim_{t\to \infty} \dfrac{t}{11! \cdot 2^{11}} = \infty$$

Comment: This is actually a problem in my calculus book. I haven't learned the method you used to determine divergence yet. I have to use the rule
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0\Rightarrow\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\text{ diverges}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $k=e^x$, notice that when $x\to\infty$, then also  $k\to\infty$.

Now, $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\ln^{10}k}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{e^x}}{x^{10}}=\infty$$